# SQLite not storing decimals correctly

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, datagridview

I have a sqlite DB with a table called tbl_invent, on form load it fills the datagridview with what is in the table. The problem is I have field names cost and sell_price which have decimals, and when the form loads it only shows the number not the decimal.

sample:

Table=1.75, DGV=1.00

```
   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    connect()
    Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from tbl_Invent", connection)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "tbl_Invent")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "tbl_Invent"
    DataGridView1.Columns(6).ValueType = GetType(Single)
    DataGridView1.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
    DataGridView1.Columns(7).ValueType = GetType(Single)
    DataGridView1.Columns(7).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"

    connection.Close()
    da.Dispose()
End Sub
```

i already check the field type it's correct "Integer", i also tried the "GetType(Single)" and "GetType(Decimal)" but still the same. any one could point me in the right direction? thank you.

---

From comments:

there is no other type in SQLite. there is only "Text", "Integer", "Real" and "Blob" also in SQLite it says integer can have decimals.

Comment: Which type is the column in the table?

Comment: @muffi as i said the field type is "Integer"

Comment: @JohnG are you sure about that? because afik you cannot set a column type before you fill it. since the column inside the DGV is not created yet. or am i the one wrong!?

Comment: If you want to show a number like "1.75", you need another type. Integer never shows you this.

Comment: @muffi there is no other type in SQLite. there is only "Text", "Integer", "Real" and "Blob" also in SQLite it says integer can have decimals.

Comment: Please check https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html. In doubt, use Text and cast it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You did not indicate which DB provider you were using, but the standard provider (from the SQLite devs) will see `Integer` and map the data to the NET `Int32` type which doesn't allow decimals.  `Real` would save fractionals as would `Decimal`.

`there is no other type in SQLite. there is only "Text", "Integer", "Real" and "Blob"`

That's true but it applies to the SQLite DB, not the DB Provider.  The standard DB Provider is cleverly written to be able to convert the 4 basic types to a variety of NET types such that the actual storage type/format becomes an implementation detail.

---

The provider code includes a number of steps, look-up tables, sub systems,  dictionaries and methods to perform conversions.  There is even a way to define custom type names. The following is a *generalized* explanation of the workings.

### Column Type Names Recognized by the SQLite NET Provider

**Byte, SByte**
INT8, INTEGER8, TINYSINT (SByte)
UINT8, UNSIGNEDINTEGER8, TINYINT (Byte)

**Integral** (short, long, signed, unsigned etc)
BIGINT, BIGUINT, COUNTER, IDENTITY, INT, INT16, INT32, INT64, INTEGER, INTEGER16, INTEGER32, INTEGER64, LONG, SMALLINT, SMALLUINT, UINT, UINT16, UINT32, UINT64, ULONG, UNSIGNEDINTEGER, UNSIGNEDINTEGER16, UNSIGNEDINTEGER32, UNSIGNEDINTEGER64

**Boolean**
BIT, BOOL, BOOLEAN, LOGICAL, YESNO

**Text/String**
CHAR, CLOB, LONGCHAR, LONGTEXT, LONGVARCHAR, MEMO, NCHAR, NOTE, NTEXT, NVARCHAR, STRING, TEXT, VARCHAR, VARCHAR2

**Numeric**
DOUBLE, FLOAT, REAL; SINGLE (Single)

**Decimal**
CURRENCY, DECIMAL, MONEY, NUMBER, NUMERIC

**BLOB**
BINARY, BLOB, GENERAL, IMAGE, OLEOBJECT, RAW, VARBINARY

**Date/Time**
DATE, DATETIME, SMALLDATE, TIME, TIMESTAMP

**GUID**
GUID, UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

Source: `SQLiteDbTypeMap` in `SQLiteConvert.cs` (version 1.0.103; September, 2016).

In essence, the DBProvider **stores** the data in the appropriate SQLite type, but when it is **read** back it uses the type you used in the table definition to convert the data back to a NET type. The SQLite provider includes a large `SQLiteConvert` class to do all the conversions for you.

---

I cannot find this documented in the wild, though it seems to be common knowledge to SQLite devotees.  Most sites just reformat the SQLite site content. It might be documented in the help file, but mine has topics with no content. Given the list, it is easy to accidentally use a valid name and discover it works.

The list incorporates the most common notations used by other DBs, plus a few NET types. For example, `Boolean` can be defined as `BIT, BOOL, BOOLEAN, LOGICAL or YESNO`.  As a result, this table definition is legal and  fully functional:

```
CREATE TABLE LiteColTypes (
    Id        INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Name      TEXT,
    ItemDate  DATETIME,
    Char3     CHAR (3),
    UINT32    UINT32,
    Value     INT16,
    VarChar5  VARCHAR (5),
    GCode     GUID,
    Price     DECIMAL,
    ItemImg   IMAGE,
    Active    BOOL,
    NotActive YESNO
);
```

There are a few things to be aware of and some useful `DateTime` options.

#### How It Works

The list comes from this code:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Builds and returns a map containing the database column types
/// recognized by this provider.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// A map containing the database column types recognized by this
/// provider.
/// </returns>
private static SQLiteDbTypeMap GetSQLiteDbTypeMap()
{
return new SQLiteDbTypeMap(new SQLiteDbTypeMapping[] {
    new SQLiteDbTypeMapping("BIGINT", DbType.Int64, false),
    new SQLiteDbTypeMapping("BINARY", DbType.Binary, false),
    new SQLiteDbTypeMapping("BIT", DbType.Boolean, true),
    new SQLiteDbTypeMapping("BLOB", DbType.Binary, true),
    new SQLiteDbTypeMapping("BOOL", DbType.Boolean, false),
    new SQLiteDbTypeMapping("BOOLEAN", DbType.Boolean, false),
    ...
    new SQLiteDbTypeMapping("GUID", DbType.Guid, false),
    new SQLiteDbTypeMapping("IMAGE", DbType.Binary, false)
    ... (many more)
```

The XML comment was retained because it is illuminating and authoritative:

> Builds and returns a map containing the database **column types recognized by this provider**.
>     (emphasis mine).

The `DbType` is crucial to the process.

#### Reading Data

The above `SQLiteDbTypeMap` associates those many, many column names it recognizes to a `DbType` which is used to determine the NET data type to return. The list is comprehensive enough that it can convert all but 1 or 2 types for you.

For example, note that `GUID` and `IMAG`* are both *stored* as `BLOB`, but the `GUID` type name is associated with a different `DbType` which allows *that* BLOB to be returned differently than an `IMAGE` BLOB.

You can also specify types via the connection object. Space and scope does not permit an explanation, but while a bit tedious, it allows you to provide the data type for custom type names.

#### Storing Data

When storing data, *you* need not fret about how it should be stored. The DB Provider will use the `DbType` passed to look up SQLite type to use (Affinity"). If you use `AddWithValue` or the (obsolete) `Add(object, object)` overload, the DBProvider will guess at the type.  It's pretty good at guessing, but dont do that.

So, this conversion is not needed:

```vb
cmd.Parameters.Add("@g", DbType.Binary).Value = myGuid.ToByteArray();
```

Use the same sort of code you would/should with any other database:

```vb
' // add trailing semicolons for c#
cmd.Parameters.Add("@n", DbType.String).Value = "Ziggy"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dt", DbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@c3", DbType.StringFixedLength, 3).Value = "XYZ123" '// see notes
cmd.Parameters.Add("@u", DbType.UInt16).Value = 3
cmd.Parameters.Add("@g", DbType.Guid).Value = myGuid
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p", DbType.Decimal).Value = 3.14D

'// 'ToByteArray()' is an extension method to convert
cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", DbType.Binary).Value = myImg.ToByteArray()
cmd.Parameters.Add("@act", DbType.Boolean).Value = True
```

Notes:

- Use the `DbType` which describes the data passed, not how *you think* it should be saved ( e.g. `DbType.Guid`, not `Binary` for a `Guid`).  The provider will perform most conversions.
- There is no `DbType.Image` so a byte array conversion *is* needed.
- Specifying a size for a `Char()/VarChar()` field does not limit the number of characters saved.  This seems like a bug because saving more characters than defined can prevent the row from loading.
- A `UInt16` works in reverse:  trying to pass an out of range value, such as -5 for a UInt16, will result in an `Overflow Exception`.  But it will return `65531` for such a value already stored.
- Size/precision parameters such as `Decimal(9,2)` for a column doesn't seem to matter.  An internal table provides fixed precision and sizes.
- For dates, pass dates and indicate `DbType.DateTime`.  There is no need to pass strings of a particular format ever.  The provider Knows Things.  (See **DateTime Options** below.)
- To save the Date only, pass only the date: `.Value = DateTime.Now.Date`.

Two Different look-up tables are used for saving versus reading data, the one thing they have in common is the `DbType` which is why it is important. Using the correct one assures that data can make the round trip.  Avoid  using `AddWithValue`.

#### Demo / Results

[image]
**Data view from a UI Browser**

Nothing special is required to load data:

```cs
 // Dim SQL = "SELECT * FROM LiteColTypes"   ' for VB
 string SQL = "SELECT * FROM LiteColTypes";      
 ...
 dbCon.Open();
 Dim dt As New DataTable();
 dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
 dgv.DataSource = dt;
```

[image]
**Same data in a DataGridView**

A DGV correctly identifies and displays the GUID, Image and Boolean columns.  The data types of each `DataColumn` are as expected:

> ```
>        Name --->    System.String (maxLen = 2147483647)  
>    ItemDate --->  System.DateTime  
>       Char3 --->    System.String (maxLen = 3)  
>      UINT16 --->    System.UInt16  
>    VarChar5 --->    System.String (maxLen = 5)  
>       GCode --->      System.Guid  
>       Price --->   System.Decimal  
>     ItemImg --->    System.Byte[]  
>      Active --->   System.Boolean  
>   NotActive --->   System.Boolean
> ```

Note that *Guid* and *Image* items were both stored as `BLOB` but are returned differently. *Active* (`BOOL`) and *NotActive* (`YESNO`) used different type names but return the same data type. Everything works as desired.

### DateTime "Issues" and Options

`TIME` as a column type name doesn't quite work as expected.  It does not parse `DateTime.Now.TimeofDay` (`Timespan`) to it.  The table maps TIME to `DbType.DateTime`.

**Do not use** `DbType.DateTime2` or `.DateTimeOffset`.  These are missing in converter look-ups so data is stored as Text in an invalid format (version 1.0.103.0).

#### UTC, Kind and Flags

The SQLite NET Provider does not support just one date format.  When saving as UTC, the data includes an indicator.  But, whether saved as Local or UTC, the `Kind` always *returns* as `Unspecified`.  Part of the remedy for this is to add `datetimekind` to your connection string:

```
`...;datetimekind=Utc;`
`...;datetimekind=Local;`
```

This will set the `Kind` for all `DateTime` values *returned* but **without converting the value.**

The remedy for *this* is to use the (relatively) new `BindDateTimeWithKind` connection flag. This will convert dates to match the `DateTimeKind` of the connection when *saved*:

```vb
Private LiteConnStr = "Data Source='C:\Temp\demo.db';Version=3;DateTimeKind=Utc;"
...
Dim dt As New DateTime(2011, 2, 11, 11, 22, 33, 444, DateTimeKind.Local)

Using dbCon = New SQLiteConnection(LiteConnStr)
    dbCon.Flags = SQLiteConnectionFlags.Default Or 
                  SQLiteConnectionFlags.BindDateTimeWithKind
    ...
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dt", DbType.DateTime).Value = dt

    ' == 2011-02-11 17:22:33.444Z   note the hour
```

Though a local date was passed, `BindDateTimeWithKind` results in it being saved as UTC to match the connection. A UTC date is returned due to the "DateTimeKind=Utc;" connection setting.

Note that `DateTimeKind` works on dates *read* while `BindDateTimeWithKind` acts when *saving* dates. Individually they can seem to make things worse; **together** the entire database becomes UTC based (or Local) with dates uniformly saved and read as the same `Kind` -- you need not do anything.

`ConnectionFlags` can be tedious to work with manually, to specify them in the connection string:

```
connx = "...;datetimekind=Utc;flags='Default, BindDateTimeWithKind';"
```

**Limitation / Issue**

The uniform `Kind` treatment works well with a `DbDataReader` and at least with Dapper. But when using a `DataTable`, the `Kind` for dates remains Unspecified.  This is apparently due to the `DateTimeMode` property in `DataColumn` and probably a design decision by Microsoft not to assume all dates in a column will always be the same `Kind`.  This manifests in other DBs as well.

When using a UTC or Local connection, the provider leaves Unspecified alone (this applies to dates in queries as well). So there should not be any undesired extra conversions: a UTC date read and 'disguised' as Unspecified in a `DataTable` isn't converted *again* in updates.

#### Ticks Format

Contrary to 'conventional wisdom' dates are not always and only saved as TEXT; to save a little space, you can save the tick value.  Since these cannot have a Time Zone indicator, the `Kind` related options can be very useful.  To enable Ticks, use the `DateTimeFormat` connection string option:

```
Private LiteConnStr = "...;datetimekind=Utc;DateTimeFormat=Ticks;..."
'e.g: 634939900800000000
```

Other `DateTimeFormat` options include **CurrentCulture**, **ISO8601** (the default), **JulianDay** and **UnixEpoch**. There is no need to change the column type name to use one of these formats.  It is still a date, the SQLite Provider handles the implementation details based on the connection flags.

**UI Browsers**

Many SQLite UI Browsers seem to only know about the four canonical types.  Perhaps this is intentional, but this limits their usefulness for NET developers and hides the capabilities of the NET provider.

SQLiteStudio (version: 3.1.0) offers a few more, but it doesn't seem to be aware of the complete list, because some very useful ones are missing (e.g. GUID, IMAGE, SINGLE, integer variants).

It *does* allow you to enter any type name you want, so Profit!

### Summary (tl;dr)

- The NET Provider adds functionality to SQLite by supporting a wide variety of type names for columns,
- Each supported name is associated with a `DBType` which determines the actual return data type
- Using the correct `DbType` when saving data assures the data makes the round trip
- The NET Provider will perform most conversions for you
- The `DateTimeKind` and `BindDateTimeWithKind` options allow for automatic, uniform TimeZone storage of dates

Above all, the NET provider makes the actual storage an *implementation detail*.

Comment: i see, well i'm using NUget package(System.Data.SQLite.Core ver 1.0.105.1) so i guess im using standard SQLite DB provider, i will try do what you suggest and will download SQLiteStudio. will update this thread afterwards. thank you for a very informative answer.

Comment: Yes, that should be the DB provider by the SQLite dev team.  SQLiteStudio isnt required -  since SQLIte is serverless, you can create tables etc via code.  The UI tools which do not allow you to add types are a problem though

Comment: That did the trick, i changed the field type to Decimal (5,2) and everything worked like a charm. thank you very much. i was using Navicat to manage my tables seems that there SQLite compatibility is restrict to those 4 types. For SQLite DB i'm only using the SQLiteStudio. thanks again.