# I get incorrect values for a column of type long when trying to read a sqlite database

Tags: c#, sqlite

I want to open a SQLite database table, which was created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE AVERAGED 
(
     TIMESTAMP INT,
     ID INT,
     KEY REAL,
     VALUE REAL,
     SAMPLES INT,

     PRIMARY KEY (TIMESTAMP, ID, KEY)
)
```

In my C# code, I use these lines to open and read the table:

```
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + @"d:\_hybridassistant\Backup\hybridassistant.db" + ";Version=2;");
con.Open();

SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("select * from Averaged", con);
// SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("select Timestamp+0 as Timestamp, ID , KEY, VALUE, SAMPLES from Averaged", con);

SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(new DateTime(((long) dr[0])/1000)); // divide by 1000 because timestamp is in milliseconds since 01.01.1970 
}
```

The active line for the `SQLiteCommand` returns incorrect values (and even negative values) for the `TIMESTAMP` column. If I use the second `SQLiteCommand` line, the values for time appear to be correct.

Comment: SQLite is perfectly capable of storing a NET DateTime value.  It also has an option to store them as UnixEpoch values so you dont have to do any converting.

Comment: @Plutonix:
I need the other way round. The sqldataadapter returns the wrong type for the column (int instead of long)

Comment: The NET SQLite provider knows how to convert the basic SQLIte types into NET datatypes for you.  You are not leveraging that ability starting with a long column for a DateTime value.  See **[SQLite not storing decimals correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44298684/1070452)**

Comment: @Plutonix, I don't get what you want to say with "You are not leveraging that ability starting with a long column for a DateTime value". I am German :-)

Comment: Ok. right now I got it (leveraging was the problem). But I cant change the design of the data table. It comes from the android App "Hybrid Assistant".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a bit research on the internet i found the solution.
I use

```
 SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("select datetime(Timestamp / 1000, 'unixepoch'), Timestamp from Averaged", con);
```

to get the correct datetime format for the timestamp column

As this approach works for this table, in another table it does not work.

```
CREATE TABLE TRIPS (TSDEB INT, TSFIN INT, NBSEC INT, NKMS INT, PRIMARY KEY (TSDEB))
```

Although the columns are all of type int, some have to be of type float, but the sqlite dataadapter cannot determine the correct datatype to use in the C# Datatable object. So i get truncated values (28 "km" instead of 28.252 "km")...

So I need more help!