# How to read the Sqlite Text to Datetime and Boolean in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite, boolean, sqlite-net

I have the table defined as below:

```
Create Table "MyMessage" ( Id TEXT primary key
                         , IsModified TEXT DEFAULT false
                         , StartTime TEXT
                         );
```

I am using `SQLite-net` assembly to query the database:

```
SQLiteConnection DbConn = new SQLiteConnection(GetDatabaseFileName());
string qry = "Select * from MyMessage";
List<MyMessage> messageList = DbConn.Query<MyMessage>( qry
                                                     , new object[]{} )
                                    .ToList<MyMessage>();
```

And here is my MyMessage class:

```
public class MyMessage
{
...
    public bool IsModified {get;set;}
    public DateTime? StartTime {get;set;}
}
```

After query, I find the IsModified is always false, and StartTime is always default datetime, not my actual value.

Is there a way that I don't have to change the data type of my columns in the table, and when query, I can query and convert them to the correct DateTime or bool?

Comment: If you define those 2 columns as `BOOLEAN` and `DATETIME`, the NET provider will return them to you that way.  Naturally,you'd have to submit the data in that form as well. I am not sure what (if any) measures the Nullable field might require.  Why is `Id` text?

Comment: Well, SQLite doesn't have boolean or datetime column types, so that's a fairly good reason. Althogh I would store the bool as an INTEGER in the database, myself.

Comment: @gnud The NET DB Provider  provides the means to return all the NET types.

Comment: Almost certainly a duplicate of **[SQLite not storing decimals correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44298684/1070452)**.  This explains the conversion mechanism for NET data types, setting it up and an overview on how it works internally

Comment: That is legacy system using text to define id, boolean and datetime...but hard to change that now. I will use string in my data model, and convert it to boolean and datetime by myself. Thanks for your answers, guys!