# Unable to save DateTime string with colon

Tags: c#, datetime

So I've been trying to figure out how to save a date time string so that it shows a colon between the hour and minute, so far everything I tried doing it just seemingly turns it into a dot.

```
com.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@DateAdded", 
                                        DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm")));
```

Gives:

```
day.month.year - hour.minute
```

When I try another way;

```
com.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@DateAdded", 
                                         DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy - HH/mm")));
```

Same thing happens:

```
day.month.year - hour.minute
```

Even tried using `\` in front of `":"` but it just gives me an error.

Comment: what is your column type?

Comment: Please [provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) showing what you're attempting to do and where you're stuck. Otherwise, it's pretty much guesswork as far as what sort of array/switch will actually help you here.

Comment: It's not clear to me how the database is involved in this.  Reduce your variables.  Are you simply claiming that `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm")` is outputting a string with a dot instead of a colon?  If that's not what you're claiming, then what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Simonare Unfortunately, SQLite does _not_ have a separate type for datetimes. It can save them as strings or numerics. https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: My bad, there was no real need in this scenario to include the fact that the strings are parameters.

Comment: How SQLite saves data is an implementation detail.  The SQLite DB Provider is perfectly capable of reading and writing Dates (or almost everything else: bool, blob,decimal, short etc). See [SQLite not storing decimals correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44298684/1070452)

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow Thanks for the detailed answer man. Love it. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The `":"` format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the--custom-format-specifier) has a *special* meaning on [custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) as;

> replace me with current culture or supplied culture time separator.

Looks like your [`CurrentCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netframework-4.7.2)'s [`TimeSeparator` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Globalization_DateTimeFormatInfo_TimeSeparator) is different than `:` so, you get a different result.

You can always escape it by the way with sorrunding single quotes like `':'` as;

```
com.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@DateAdded",
                                        DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy - HH':'mm")));
```

It is the same as [The `"/"` custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the--custom-format-specifier-1) as well. You tested it on your second code part by the way.

As addition, SQLite saves your datetime values with [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) if you decide to keep them as string. So, in your case, you should use it like;

```
com.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@DateAdded",
                                        DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss.fff")));
```

Answer (score 0):

":" in a custom DateTime format string will output the localized time separator. If you want a literal ":" you have to escape it using a backslash, i.e.

`DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy - HH\\:mm")`

or

`DateTime.Now.ToString(@"dd.MM.yyyy - HH\:mm")`

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)