# SQLite inserting string data with parameters leads to invalid cast exception

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

Good morning,

I was working on some unit tests for our SQLite 3 database code, and ran into this interesting problem. Here is a unit test that passes with flying colors:

```
[Fact]
public void TestDB()
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".sqlite");
    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={fi.FullName};Version=3;"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        conn.ExecuteNonQuery("CREATE Table Temp(A INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, B STRING);");

        string sql = "INSERT INTO Temp (A, B) VALUES (@A, @B)";
        string s = "Test";
        using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@A", System.Data.DbType.Int32).Value = 1;
            command.Parameters.Add("@B", System.Data.DbType.String).Value = s;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        sql = $"SELECT B FROM Temp WHERE A = 1";
        using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn))
        using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            bool read = reader.Read();
            Assert.True(read);
            if (read)
            {
                Assert.False(reader.IsDBNull(0));
                string b = reader.GetString(0);
                Assert.Equal(s, b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but if I change one line:

```
string s = "1";
```

An `InvalidCastException` is thrown on the `reader.GetString(0)` line. Thinking maybe an additional hint is necessary by specifying the column, I also tried this:

```
SQLiteParameter a = new SQLiteParameter("@A", System.Data.DbType.Int32, "A") { Value = 1 };
SQLiteParameter b = new SQLiteParameter("@B", System.Data.DbType.String, "B") { Value = s };
command.Parameters.Add(a);
command.Parameters.Add(b);
```

Nothing changed.

Anyone have any ideas how to use parameters and insert data into a string column where the data is a numeric string?

Comment: Not sure a data type of `STRING` is really recognised by SQLite (see 3.1 Determination of column affinity https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html, sounds like it would default to numeric for the affinity). I haven't tested that theory but maybe try `TEXT` instead of `STRING`.

Comment: STRING is a perfectly [legal column type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312936/1070452) for SQLite, the same problem has been known to happen with TEXT as well as VARCHAR columns when using `.GetString()`. The built in converter is kicking in at a wrong time I think.  One solution is to use `reader[0].ToString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@steve16351 had the answer.

The problem was actually in `CREATE TABLE` where the B column was type `STRING`. SQLite uses type `TEXT`.

Changing that to: `CREATE TABLE Temp(A INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, B TEXT);` fixed the problem.

Thank you!