# Why can I not query a DATETIME field using EF6 and SQlite?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, entity-framework-6, linqpad

I have a WPF application which uses EF6 and Sqlite. I'm trying to run a relatively simple query which compares dates. I have read a thousand articles on sqlite and dates and I'm still stuck.

I don't think this has anything to do with the time part of the comparison (i.e. trying to compare date only). I understand that I could use a start and end datetime to capture records which fall between. I think this is to do with the actual sql that is being generated by the orm.

I think the issue comes from the SQL generated by EF6. In SQlite my table has a DATETIME field which is a string value in the following format: "2019-03-23 00:00:00.000".

When I run the query as part of the application in VS debug mode, the query returns no results and I can see from the logged sql, the parameter in the where clause is  p__linq__0: '23/03/2019 00:00:00'

When I run the very same query using Linqpad (targeting the same db with the same dll reference) the query does indeed return records as I expect and I noticed that the sql generated by linqpad uses this format for the parameter @p__linq__0 DateTime2 = '2019-03-23 00:00:00.0000000'

In the application, I reference System.Data.SQLite (v 1.0.110.0) - I'm not sure what linqpad uses.

I don't know how to influence the generated SQL in the application but linqpad suggests that it should be possible to generate some compatible sql.

In case it helps or I'm barking up the wrong tree, here is my linq query. The comparison is with the parameter "today" which creates the different sql parameters as above.

```c#
public IEnumerable<Menu> GetTodaysMenus()
{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;

    var menus = _context.Menus
          .Select(x => new
          {
             x,
             x.SalesBusinessType,
             Date = x.MenuDays.Select(y => y.CalendarDate)
          })
         .Where(x => x.x.DeletedAt == null &&
                     x.x.Published == true &&
                     x.Date.Contains(today))
         .AsEnumerable()
         .Select(x => x.x);

  return menus;
}
```

I can reproduce the scenario and I'm able to change the database configuration but I'm not sure what to do. I want to be able to use date comparison in my application as I seem to be able to do when using linqpad.

UPDATE:

This updated query gets the record I was expecting. I'm still unsure why and what was "wrong" with the original

```c#
public IEnumerable<Menu> GetTodaysMenus()
        {
            string today = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");

            var menus = _context.Menus
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x,
                    x.SalesBusinessType,
                    x.MenuDays,
                    Date = x.MenuDays.Select(y => y.CalendarDate.ToString())
                })
                .Where(x => x.x.DeletedAt == null &&
                            x.x.Published == true &&
                            x.Date.Contains(today))
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => x.x);

            return menus;
        }
```

UPDATE 2:

Direct comparisons work like this for example (DateTime == today) or in this example DateTime collection Contains(today) however ranges (i.e. datetime >= today) don't work.

Comment: What is the data type of `CalendarDate`?   You say it's a DateTime field, but then you say it's a string.  DBs do not store Dates or Times as strings, but will allow you to query against a formatted string.

Comment: Also you don't need that intermediate `Select` you can have `x.MenuDays.Select(y => y.CalendarDat).Contains(today)` in the `Where` clause.

Comment: How SQLite stores the date on disk is an *implementation detail*. The standard [NET SQLite provider returns dates and other NET datatype quite well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312936/1070452)

Comment: @mjwills In that case the OP might want to try the query with the date formatted as a string instead.

Comment: @mjwills - I'm not getting an error, rather no records returned. I cant use a string for today in the query as the entity has the field as a c# DateTime. I don't know what StartsWith is as the Date field on the anonymous is a collection of DateTime. The Where targets the Date which is on the anonymous so I think needs to come after the select.

Comment: @juharr - The data type of the CalendarDate is DateTime in c# but I understood that Sqlite stores datetimes as either a string, real or int. The db is created from code using this nuget package I found SQLite.CodeFirst.

Comment: I thought I was onto something when I saw the difference in generated sql parameters between the logged sql output in the application and the sql generated when using linqpad...

Comment: @MakeStackOverflowGoodAgain - I would have hoped that the provider returns a decent DateTime object. I have tried a version of my code whereby I pull all the records back into memory (that particular table is small). the subsequant linq query works and I can get t he record. I doesn't however work when the query is sent to the database straight away. For obvious reasons, I don't want to always pull back all the records in memory.

Comment: What if you try something like `x.MenuDays.Select(y => y.CalendarDate.ToString()).Contains(todayAsString)`.  That should either result is some type of SQL that will allow you to compare the column to a formatted date string that should match, or EF will give an error.

Comment: `my table has a DATETIME field which is a string value in the following format: "2019-03-23 00:00:00.000"`  A string is not a date and dates do not have a format.  If you define the column as string, the DB provider cannot help you (see the link). There might also be something *else* wrong, but storing dates as string builds in conversion issues as well as format problems

Comment: @MakeStackOverflowGoodAgain - I was just reading from this [link](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) which described the three types of storage mechanisms Sqlite uses but as you say, I shouldn't care. I just mentioned it in case it was relevant to my issue. The entity in the application is a c# DateTime and I only want to deal in DateTimes but when the sql is sent to the db directly something is causing the mismatch. I'm just not sure what.

Comment: @juharr - So your suggestion worked. It generated the sql with the a parameter format which matched the record... Still unsure why and how the strings vs DateTimes are converted... Never the less - thanks.