# sqLite dotnet reader reading wrong int type

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a sqlite table I've created using this command:

```
CREATE TABLE PriceTable (DateTime INT PRIMARY KEY, Bid REAL NOT NULL, Ask REAL NOT NULL)
```

and then in the DateTime column I've stored C# DateTime tick values, so the table is populated with data like this (if I use a database browser such as https://sqlitebrowser.org/):

[image]

However when I read the table from another C# application, and look at GetFieldType of the SQliteDataReader, it says the first column is an Int32, and then returns values like "-499740304", which seems to be casting it to an Int32.

How can I get the SQliteDataReader to return the right values?

Comment: SQLIte can store anything in any column since there is no server or other mechanism to stop it.  Those tick values clearly are not INT even though that is what you used in your CREATE TABLE.  To Store DateTime ticks, the column should be `DateTime` and use the *connection string* option to store DateTime as ticks.  **[More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312936/1070452)**

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp, thanks, clearly you are right. They are not INT. Is there any way to change the column type without recreating the table?

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp, or is it possible to force the c# reader to read it as a different type?

Comment: Did you try a simple `ALTER TABLE` or *maybe* your UI Browser?  I know SQL LIte Studio can do it, but last time I looked SQLite Browser didnt support/wasnt aware of the full range of data types supported

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp it seems sqlLite doesn't allow ALTER TABLE to modify columns, however it can be done in my UI browser, or alternatively though commands as outlined here: https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/sqlite/sqlite-alter-table. Thanks

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp red herring as the DateTime column is defined as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, the column can only contain an integer value else there would be a data mismatch error. A column defined with INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is an alias of the rowid column and as per *Any column in an SQLite version 3 database, except an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column, may be used to store a value of any storage class.* [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3][(https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). Issue is that the integer is greater then 32 bit signed integer (an integer in SQLite can be up to 64 bit signed).

Answer (score 0):

If you read [DateTime.Ticks Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netframework-4.8) :-

> DateTime.Ticks Property Definition
>
> Namespace: System Assemblies:
>
> System.Runtime.dll, mscorlib.dll, netstandard.dll
>
> Gets the number of
>   ticks that represent the date and time of this instance.
>
> C#
>
> Copy public **long** Ticks { get; }
>
> Property Value **Int64** The number of
>   ticks that represent the date and time of this instance.
>
> The value is
>   between DateTime.MinValue.Ticks and DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks.

**As such you need to use Int64**