# Show 0/1 as yes/no in DevExpress XtraGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, devexpress, xtragrid

I had this code for a regular DataGridView, and I'm having trouble getting the same effect on the XtraGrid:

```
private void RosterGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 7 && e.Value is long)
    {
        e.Value = (long)e.Value == 0 ? "No" : "Yes";
    }
}
```

The issue is I am using SQLite and it doesn't have any true boolean data type, or else this would be easy. The column is set up in the DB to only accept 0 and 1, kind of a makeshift boolean.

Comment: The core SQLite DB doesnt have a bool, but in the end, that is just an im,plementation detail.  The [SQLite Provider objects know how to convert and do so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44298684/1070452)

Comment: Very interesting.  I changed my database to use bool instead, and it worked.  I figured since it wasn't an option it wasn't supported.  Thank you

Comment: The proper way yo do 'thanks' on SO is to up vote the answer - or any post which helps.  The brief [tour] explains how the site works

Answer (score 0):

With DevExpress you [can set up the specific column to use the RepositoryItemCheckEdit](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/753/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/data-editing-and-validation/modify-and-validate-cell-values#custom_editors_code):

```
// Assign a repository item to a column            
RepositoryItemCheckEdit checkEdit = new RepositoryItemCheckEdit();
gridControl.RepositoryItems.Add(checkEdit);
gridView.Columns["Mark"].ColumnEdit = checkEdit;
```

After that, you can set up the [ValueChecked](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit.ValueChecked), [ValueUnchecked](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit.ValueUnchecked) and ValueGrayed properties specify the values that correspond to the editor's checked, unchecked and indeterminate state, respectively. The default values of the ValueChecked, ValueUnchecked and ValueGrayed properties are `true, false and null`, respectively. You can assign custom values to these properties as your logic requires:

```
checkEdit.ValueChecked = (long)1;
checkEdit.ValueUnchecked = (long)0;
```

With this approach, you can avoid any value conversion operations when displaying and editing values in GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use the CustomColumnDisplayText event on the gridView

```
private void gridView1_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column = <yourColumn>)
    {
        e.DisplayText = (long) e.Value == 1 ? "Yes" : "No";
    }
}
```