# How can I chose the latest date in a table using query

Tags: c#, sqlite

This is what I did, which is wrong.
My date field is stored as (MM/DD/YYYY)

```
Select Name,Family,ID,max(Dates) from MyTable group by name,family
```

Comment: Check out the DATE() function.

Comment: I did, but still I don't know how to select the latest date from a table.

Comment: All I need is one sample query showing how the last date can be retrieved,

Comment: Please edit your question to show your exact query. It looks like you are using the raw `dates` column. You need to use the `DATE()` function to convert the date string into a date object.

Comment: Select ID,Name,max(Dates) from Mytable group by Name

Comment: Please [edit] your question

Comment: How do I edit it ?
I already typed it in edit box.

Comment: Click on the [edit] link in my comment or the edit link below your question.

Comment: I did that, it has a title, body and summary.
That's where I put it in, but it doesn't show like it suppose to.
I'm not a pro. :((

Comment: You need to make some changes the click submit to save them. The changes should include the query that you have tried.

Comment: Can you just show me how it's written ?
I cannot find the place to make it HTML friendly.

Comment: Use one of the formats [listed here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) instead.

Comment: My field is formatted like MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: I figured it out how to edit my question in right format. I just needed someone to tell me that I had to do 4 spaces before typing.
Now I just don't know why it gives me a red error saying it could not be submitted.

Comment: Define the column as `DateTime` so the dates can be treated as dates and the [NET DB Provider objects will do the rest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312936/1070452)

Comment: There is no DateTime option as type.
I can only choose INTEGER,TEXT,BLOB,REAL NUMERIC

Comment: Actually, you can type in anything you want, even use make up custom data types. SQLIte is server-less so there is nothing to complain.  The link shows how it works

Comment: You need to use one of the formats in that documentation link if you want to be able to sort dates in sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **Dates** is a **TEXT** column containing values stored as **MM/DD/YYYY**, calling **MAX()** on it doesn't produce the latest date because Sqlite will do an **alphanumeric** sort on the column, which will sort by month first.

You need to properly convert the Dates TEXT values into **DATE** values and then when you call MAX() on the DATE values, Sqlite will sort the way you expect and produce the latest date value.

DATE values can be created using **DATE()** but the parameter to DATE() needs to be a date string in **ISO** format (**YYYY-MM-DD**). So, we need to parse out the existing TEXT string values using substr(), then build an ISO date from the parsed-out date part components, then finally pass that ISO date into DATE() as the parameter.

But, a side effect of this is that the query output will now show the max date in ISO format, so if you need the date in the original format, you would need to include that separately.

So, something like this:

```
SELECT Name, Family, ID, Dates, MAX(DATE(SUBSTR(Dates, 7, 4) || '-' || SUBSTR(Dates, 1, 2) || '-' || SUBSTR(Dates, 4, 2))) FROM MyTable
```

Comment: @SamCanyon you're welcome. Feel free to mark the answer as answered, that's how it works.

Comment: Im not sure how to do that. If you tell me I can do it.

Comment: Click the check mark icon you will see beneath the vote count in this answer.