# C# SQLite get real value from DB generates Invalid Cast Exception

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to get a real value from a SQLiteDatabase using C#.
Everything is working fine with exception of the real values.

I use the following code to get the data from the database

```
// Building query...
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * " +
    "FROM ProductsPrice p " +
    "WHERE p.ProductId = @ProductId " +
    "ORDER BY Date DESC " +
    "LIMIT 1";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", ProductId);

// Execute query
using (SQLiteConnection conn = DatabaseService.getDbConnection())
using (cmd.Connection = conn)
{

    //Open Connection
    conn.Open();

    using (SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            //var x = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("NetPrice"));
            //var y = dr["GrossPrice"];
            //var x = dr.GetOrdinal("GrossPrice").GetType();

            price.Id = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("Id"));
            price.NetPrice = dr.GetDouble(dr.GetOrdinal("NetPrice"));
            price.GrossPrice = dr.GetDouble(dr.GetOrdinal("GrossPrice"));
            price.VAT = dr.GetDouble(dr.GetOrdinal("Vat"));
            price.AddedDate = dr.GetDateTime(dr.GetOrdinal("Date"));
        }

}
```

object price is as follows:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public double NetPrice  { get; set; }
public double GrossPrice  { get; set; }
public double VAT  { get; set; }
public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
```

The database columns are as follows:

```
ID = INTEGER
NetPrice = REAL
GrossPrice = REAL
Vat = REAL
Date = datetime
```

When I get the NetPrice this works because the value is 2. But when I get the GrossPrice I get an Invalid Cast Exception because this value is 2.42.
What am I doing wrong here?

If I check the GetType() of the GrossPrice it is a Int32. But that is impossible with the value 2.42.
If I use `price.GrossPrice = Convert.ToDouble(dr["GrossPrice"])` I get as result 2 (without .42).
If I change the SQLite DB column type to Double or Float. It does not change anything. 
I'm out of ideas...

Comment: What is the type of "price" variable? If its your custom class, please include that also in your question. I think you have wrongly defined GrossPrice (int) on "price" object's class definition.

Comment: If the property type were wrong, it would be a compilation error, not a runtime `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. Don't know if it helps, but I have some project with SQLite database, and I've defined "decimal" in .NET as a type and FLOAT in SQLite database. And it works OK. Although I'm using EF, so I wouldn't know exactly which method to call on DataReader (GetFloat maybe)?

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. I changed the DB columns to float and used GetFloat() to get the data. But still I get the InvalidCastExeption..
This is the stacktrace:

System.InvalidCastException: 
Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.VerifyType(Int32 i, DbType typ)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.GetFloat(Int32 i)

Comment: I tried using decimal instead of double. That gives a different result. Now I get an 'FormatExeption: Input string was not in a correct format'. Also when I directly read the GetDecimal into a var. It stills gives that exception.

Comment: I have created a sample project and tried your code and it worked OK. I've used NuGet package "System.Data.SQLite.Core" version 1.0.109.2 to access SQLite database (with following connection string: "Data Source=C:\\Temp\\DB1.db; Version=3;"

Comment: I got the issue! The value in my database was not 2.42 (dot seperated) but 2,42 (comma seperated). I changed the value manual to a dot and now it is working! 
My Windows uses comma by default.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's odd. I've done it the same in my sample DB and got the same exception. I though this should not matter when dealing with float types (reading/writing), only when converting from string to float or sth like that.

Comment: It has to do with the databse localization and my windows localization. These are not the same. I know from experience that Oracle databases also have trouble with this. Learned that SQLite has the same issue :-) Thanks again.

Comment: I dug some more and this explains a lot: "SQLite is inherently un-typed.  All datatypes in SQLite are natively strings."

Comment: You should avoid `Parameters.AddWithValue` especially with SQLIte which leaves it to the DB Provider to guess at the data type.  Since it it serverless, you can save anything to any column which can trash the DB (which is what happened here on a small scale).  You can/should store currency data as decimal.  [See here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312936/1070452)