# How do you save a hashset to a SQLite Db in c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2019, hashset

I am looking to use SQLite for saving and retrieving custom player data. This will be loaded when the player logs in and saved when it changes.

I see that I only have 4 types available to me though:

> NULL. The value is a NULL value.
>
> INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8
> bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.
>
> REAL. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE
> floating point number.
>
> TEXT. The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding
> (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).
>
> BLOB. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

Now BLOB looks to be the one to use? but how do i save a hashset as a blob and load it as a hashset? or am i going about this wrong?

the hashset will be a list of waypoints visited (using hashset to eliminate any duplicats) based on the following model:

```
 public class WaypointObject
{
    public string MapName { get; set; }
    public Point WaypointLocation { get; set; }
    public string WorldName { get; set; }
}
```

And will be saved from, loaded into

```
public HashSet<WaypointObject> waypoints = new HashSet<WaypointObject>();
```

I am learning all i can on sqlite at mo and im sure there must be a way? but I can not see how to do it.

Any help appreciated

Comment: A) A hashset is a *collection* so you are likely going to want to save each item as its own row. B) the NET DB Provider extends the supported datatypes considerably.  See **[SQLite not storing decimals correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44298684/sqlite-not-storing-decimals-correctly/44312936#44312936)** C) Please do not include irrelevant tags - your question has nothing to do with Visual Studio

Comment: a) Not sure about each item on its own row, wouldnt each player have their own row, as each player will have their own unique hashset<WaypointObject> "list" 

unless you mean 5 columns:
playername - mapname - waypoint x - waypoint y - world name 

on load retrieve all entries that match playername and addthem to the hashset.
but then how do you prevent it saving the same ones again each time it does a save. Very confused
b and c: I am a hobby coder, I only ask when i cant find the solution after a lot of searching im using system.data.sqlite in visual studio s assumed that was relevant

Comment: do you mean a waypointdb for each player? hmmm is that possible, i assumed too many files would be an issue and one would be be better - however one per player would be preferable for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The below code try may solve

```js
using ( var db = new SQLiteConnection( new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DbPath ) ) 
{
     db.InsertAll(waypoints);
    //For insert
      db.UpdateAll(waypoints);
    //for update
}
```