# DataGridView tries to turn my SQLIte DateTimes to Image

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sqlite, datagridview

So i am using the `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` library v 3.1.3.0 to read some data out of a local Sqlite db.
I have been representing this data without flaws in a simple DataGridView for a while now but suddenly the users report to me that there are some error messages and the Form does not run...
It's this error message:

```
---------------------------
DataGridView Default Error Dialog
---------------------------
The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:


System.FormatException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Drawing.Image'. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Drawing.Image'.
   at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToType(Type type, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Formatter.ChangeType(Object value, Type type, IFormatProvider formatInfo)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Windows.Forms.Formatter.ChangeType(Object value, Type type, IFormatProvider formatInfo)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Formatter.FormatObjectInternal(Object value, Type targetType, TypeConverter sourceConverter, TypeConverter targetConverter, String formatString, IFormatProvider formatInfo, Object formattedNullValue)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Formatter.FormatObject(Object value, Type targetType, TypeConverter sourceConverter, TypeConverter targetConverter, String formatString, IFormatProvider formatInfo, Object formattedNullValue, Object dataSourceNullValue)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.GetFormattedValue(Object value, Int32 rowIndex, DataGridViewCellStyle& cellStyle, TypeConverter valueTypeConverter, TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter, DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)

To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event.
```

I do my selects manually, becasue i prefer to do so... And apparently there is this very peciluiar issue that becasue i try to format the DateTimes differently with the STRFTIME function in my select.

So basically my select looks something like this:

```sql
SELECT column1, column2, strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M', start_time) as start_time, strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M', confirm_time) as confirm_time, strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M', real_end_time) as real_end_time FROM myTable
```

The SQLite data is stored in a `System.Data.DataTable` and then fed to the DataGridView as it's datasource.

```
DataTable temp = new DataTable();
temp = Sqlite.selectQuery($"SELECT ...");

dataGridView1.DataSource = temp;
```

Because my users wish to use the european `dd.MM.yyyy HH24:mm` format, the default `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format isn't applicable.
But when using the formatting function, the above mentioned exception pops up and my dates look like error icons: [image: date error icons]

Any ideas how to achieve my desired dateformat without the troublesome error?

Example datetimes from SQLite:

```
2020-08-11 20:41:00
2020-06-03 12:07:00
2020-06-03 12:07:00
2020-07-25 02:42:00
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Storing a date is different than displaying it.  Your retrieval conversion must conform to the format being stored in SQLite.  Once you've retrieved it, you can format it any way you wish.

Comment: The standard NET DB provider for SQLite is perfectly capable of storing and returning DateTime data...and without the `strftime` overhead and certainly without worrying about 'formats'.  To get started, see: **[SQLite not storing decimals correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44298684/sqlite-not-storing-decimals-correctly/44312936#44312936)**

Comment: Really puzzled why your strftime calls have two closing brackets per one opening bracket.. What am I missing?

Comment: @CaiusJard must be becasue i made an error pasting the code example... Thanks for the hint. Gonna fix it in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Aaand that's why you shouldn't get your DB to format your dates into strings on behalf of your front end.

Select the date into your datatable as a date and show it in a datagridviewtextboxcolumn with a DefaultCellStyle.Format of `"dd.MM.yy HH:mm"` so that the front end does the formatting.

Your life will probably get a lot easier if you add a strongly typed dataset (even if you don't add tableadapters, dataadapters can still fill strongly typed datatables), design some tables and columns into it to match what youre selecting from your db, then drop the table out of the Data Sources window and onto the form; you'll get a grid already binded to the datatable, with a set of columns that have sensible defaults and can be customized by you:

[image]

All you need to do with this to get the grid to show some data is fill the datatable (either use tableadapters or take some existing dataadapter with its query etc and get it to Fill the `SomeBlahBlahDataset.SomeBlahTable` that is already bound to the grid at design time

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I wanted to avoid the Strongly typed dataset becasue of the dynamics of the project and the indeciciveness on what exactly the users wanted to have shown for a while.
While i based my  expectiations of the values being String typed anyway, as the SQLite has no dedicated DATE/DATETIME format (based on https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype ) and uses a string representation anyway, i see that the suggested approach would be helpful.

What baffles me is that i has been working for weeks and suddenly decided to stop.