# Convert SQLite timestamp to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, timestamp, system.data.sqlite

I am trying to assign a property of an object the value of a column containing a timestamp in SQLite. Currently the property is of type DateTime, but I've tried string type with no change. I've tried using `Convert.ToDateTime(rdr.GetString(5).ToString())` with no change.

Here's the exception I get:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.VerifyType(Int32 i, DbType typ)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.GetDateTime(Int32 i)
   at ConsoleHelpTicket.Data.FillQueue(SQLiteConnection conn, Queue`1 queue) in E:\...\Data.cs:line 142
```

Here's the property declaration:

```cs
public DateTime OpenDate { get; set; }
```

Here's the method where I try the assignment:

```cs
public static void FillQueue(SQLiteConnection conn, Queue<Ticket> queue)
        {
            try
            {
                var cmd = new SQLiteCommand($"select * from Tickets order by OpenDate desc;", conn);
                using SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
                    ticket.Tid = rdr.GetInt32(0);
                    ticket.Title = rdr.GetString(2);
                    ticket.Description = rdr.GetString(3);
                    ticket.OpenDate = rdr.GetString(5); <---------- PROBLEM LINE
                    ticket.ClosedDate = rdr.GetString(6);
                    ticket.Open = rdr.GetBoolean(7);
                    ticket.Location = rdr.GetString(8);
                    System.Console.WriteLine($"Added TID: {rdr.GetInt32(0)} Title: {rdr.GetString(2)} to queue.");

                    queue.Enqueue(ticket);
                }
            }
```

Comment: If the column is defined as an actual TIMESTAMP, SQLIte should be able to convert it to NET DateTime.  It is not clear why you treat it as string.  See **[SQLite not storing decimals correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44298684/1070452)**

Comment: what's your Ticket class look like? Specifically OpenDate

Comment: I set the SQL column as time stamp initially, but after reading the documentation for SQLite it looks like it doesn't support time as a data type, it's all just text type.
Here's the property in my ticket class I'm trying to write to: public DateTime OpenDate { get; set; }

Comment: If I set it to string type is throws an exception too.

Comment: I changed the columns data type back to TIMESTAMP, no change.

                                CommentTime TIMPSTAMP,
                                OpenDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                                ClosedDate TIMESTAMP

Comment: Opendate is defined as a datetime and you're getting the dB value as string. Try assign to a string variable and later parse to datetime

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the problem(s).

I was using SQLite's TIMESTAMP as the default column value, and I was allowing that to be set for the column value on every insert. I edited C# insert line to insert `DateTime.Now`. Yes SQLite supports TimeStamp as a data type, but the documentation says it's really stored as a string. [See the documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

After much troubleshooting I realized **I got my column numbers mixed up** and I was trying to import parse a bool as time, which obviously will throw an exception. I'm rewriting my code now to be more dynamic to avoid this type of problem in the future.

Finally I ended up using this line `ticket.OpenDate = DateTime.Parse(rdr.GetString(6));` to successfully assign the column value to a `DateTime` property. My thinking is that if SQLite is storing it as a string, I should retrieve it as a string and parse it to `DateTime`. I'm also storing the value as a native `DateTime` value from C# instead of relying on the `TimeStamp` value from SQLite. I haven't tested to see if I can parse a `TimeStamp` value though.